# The LLDB display "Summary Unavailable" when debug variable of type std::__1::string

Tags: android, android-source, lldb

I also tried gdb,but still have this problem, anyone know why ？

[screenshot of the scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M539j.png)

Answer (score 1):

"Summary Unavailable" is printed when there was a problem getting the string data out of the std::string object.  Maybe `self->name` isn't initialized yet?

You can examine the variable's contents by using the `v` command with `--raw` to show the underlying object w/o formatters, maybe that will give you a clue as to what is wrong?  You can do that in your case with:

```
(lldb) v --raw self->name
```

The string contents are usually in `__r.__value_.__s.__data_` inside the std::string object.

Comment: I tried,the results are shown below:

(lldb) v --raw storage
(std::__1::string *) storage = 0x00000078e05b9e70

Comment: That's a pointer, and lldb doesn't disclose pointers by default in `v`.  To see what's going on with the contents you want to do `v --raw *storage`.

Comment: No content shown....                                                                                                                                         (lldb)v --raw *storage                                                                                 (std::__1::string) storage = {}

Comment: That makes it sound like the pointer itself is bad.  If you run the `memory read` command on the original pointer value, does that succeed?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing: "summary unavailable" for `std::string` and I could not navigate into the hierarchy of types of other variables. Everything was back when I turned off the use of precompiled headers...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34738020)

Comment: I beg to disagree, removing the use of precompiled headers get rid of this problem, I guess that the precompiled headers are stripped from debug information that are necessary for lldb to display complete information.